transposing data - dbt pivot util erroring out
My dbt model stg_hired_data looks as below:

I want to transpose this table so my resultant data should look like:

Below is my dbt model that i tried. I made an unpivot of source data and then pivot the model to transpose the result:
--stg_hired_data_unpiv
    {{
        dbt_utils.unpivot(
            relation=ref("stg_hired_data"),
            cast_to="varchar",
            exclude=["component","segment"],
            field_name="metric_name",
            value_name="metric_value"
        )
    }}
--stg_hired_data_piv (final view that shows transposed format)
    with
    test_data as (
    select
        component,
        metric_name,
        {{
            dbt_utils.pivot(
                component,
                dbt_utils.get_column_values(ref("stg_hired_data_unpiv"), "segment"),
                then_value = metric_value,
            )
        }}
    from {{ ref("stg_hired_data_unpiv") }}
    group by component,metric_name
    )
    
    select * from test_data 

In the pivoting query, at the dbt_utils.get_column_values(ref("stg_hired_data_unpiv"), "segment") line i see error  syntax error at or near "=" . There is no more detail in the error message. Any help on how this can be resolved in dbt?

I don't know dbt at all, but the extra comma at the end of then_value=metric_value, line looks funny.  Is that part of the syntax?

have you tried compiling the Jinja to SQL? the error mentions a syntax error, so that would definitely help to spot it.
